# Pros and Cons of table name having spaces

Tags: sql, mysql

In one of my project, it was required to have a table with space in between. Some suggest me not to include spaces because it is not a good technique.

we can still implement it using single-double quotes for table name in queries. But i need a solid backing for not opting spaces. Please help.

Comment: Please share the requirement. I'm gonna post it to thedailywtf.com and become famous.

Answer (score 8):

It makes it harder to read, creates complexity if you ever want to do dynamic SQL.  Spaces in the tables names on the other hand add no value whatsoever.

Mr. Anderson points out that its tedious. This is true enough, but more importantly it adds unnecessary tediousness.

Comment: Besides it really tedious quoting the table name every time you fire of some sql.

Comment: harder to read - I would assume (no facts here) the spaces would lead to better word pattern identification by the brain, and thus easier to read? or do you prefer: Iwouldassume(nofactshere)thespaces wouldleadtobetterwordpatternidentificationbythebrain,andthuseasier toread? ;) Could you maybe what you mean by easier to read as I think you mean something else.

Comment: creates complexity if you ever want to do dynamic SQL - Not much really, just make sure you surround all table names with [] and you good to go. I think there is even an method call for something similar.

Comment: @RobertMacLean "just adding" identifier qualifiers does indeed add complexity since its more than not doing anything. Also [] doesn't work here since its MySQL which uses backticks. Also by readability compare `FROM Posts p inner join [Post History] ph on p.id = ph.postid` vs `FROM Posts p inner join PostHistory ph on p.id = ph.postid`

Comment: @ConradFrix Didn't realise that MySQL didn't use [], thanks for that! I think the complexity added is minor - you are building dynamic SQL, you likely have everything to add it with minimal or no code changes.

Answer (score 4):

I would never use spaces (nor other special characters) in table or column names.

Out of lazyness is one point (so typing SQL queries is a lot easier because you don't need those dreaded quotes)

Secondly a lot of tools out there might still have problems with non-standard table names.

Btw: the quote character for non-standard object names is a double quote (") 
If you really go down that road, I would highly recommend to put MySQL into "ANSI Mode" in order to be compatible with the rest of the (DBMS) world.

(Single quotes are for character literals, double quotes for "escaping" non-standard names)

Comment: So I know the ones to avoid, what tools have problems with this?

Comment: I did not have specific ones in mind. I just noticed (on various DBMS) that having non-standard names sometimes leads to surprises

Comment: "I would never use spaces (nor other special characters) in table or column names" -- how come your handle isn't `AHorseWithNoName`, then? :)

Comment: :) - because I use underscores which is neither a space nor a special character (and I sure hope SO doesn't create one table for each user...)

Comment: no spaces, no special chars, no capitals, no reserved word is my way :)