# How to add items to database?

Tags: c#, database, listbox

Im trying to add items to my database using C#.
I have a database with 2 tables:

"Project Parts"

"Project Table" , in this table there is a column named "Project Name"

but im getting this error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token
>   line offset = 21,Token in error = Table ]

Here is the code im using.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlCEC.Open();

        //Project_List.Items.Add(new_project_name.Text.ToString());
        SqlCeCommand sqlCEcommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Project Table(Project Name) VALUES(@Project Name)", sqlCEC);
        sqlCEcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project Name", new_project_name.Text);

        sqlCEcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlCEC.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this question and it's answers: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436440/pros-and-cons-of-table-name-having-spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436440/pros-and-cons-of-table-name-having-spaces).

Comment: I don't think the spaces are valid in table names. I just tried to create a test CE database and it complained when I used the table and column names you've given. Are they just example names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlCEC.Open();
    SqlCeCommand sqlCEcommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Project Table]([Project Name]) VALUES([@Project Name])", sqlCEC);
    sqlCEcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project Name", new_project_name.Text);
    sqlCEcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCEC.Close();
}
```

Because your database objects contains spaces, you need to enclose them with `[]`

My humble advice is, **never** use spaces or other special characters in your tables or your column names.

Comment: thanks. think i got it working. now it cant find the proper column name, but I will start renaming the tables and column, with no special characters. :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the tables and fields that have spaces with brackets.

> SqlCeCommand sqlCEcommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Project Table] ([Project Name]) VALUES (@ProjectName)", sqlCEC);

Also, don't include any spaces in the parameter variable, try changing it to just `@ProjectName`:

```
sqlCEcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", new_project_name.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Table names and column names with a space in them usually have to be wrapped in `[` and `]`. Also, parameters cannot have spaces in them

```
INSERT INTO [Project Table]([Project Name]) VALUES(@ProjectName)
```

and

```
sqlCEcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", new_project_name.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

When a database object contains spaces it is required to enclose this name with square brackets.
Also do not name your parameters using spaces.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlCEC.Open();
    SqlCeCommand sqlCEcommand = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Project Table] " + 
             "([Project Name]) VALUES(@ProjectName)", sqlCEC);
    sqlCEcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", new_project_name.Text);
    sqlCEcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCEC.Close();
}
```